# Powerapps basic styling

Tags: powerapps

Im building a small powerapps app but has some issues finding a couple of styling properties.

1. ***Hint text color***: where is this property located. I can easily change entered text color but the hinttext seems to be harder to find. Anyone that knows where this is located?
2. ***Browsegallery individual item styling***: Im trying to acheive the feeling of cards for the browsegallery items / list. And to remove the default border / outline of each data item. But all styling applied after selecting an item (like border and fill) is applied to the whole control, not each item. For example, if applying fill to black on an item, the whole gallery gets a black fill.

Probably just a matter of locating the right parameter, perhaps someone could give me a hint as where to edit these?

Answer (score 0):

***Hint text color***: There is `HintText` color property in powerapps and

***Browsegallery individual item styling:*** select `List Item` and goto `Fill` and write the code `If(ThisItem.IsSelected,Blue,AntiqueWhite)`

Comment: This is actually what i expect but that doesnt work. I selected the SearchTextBox and went through the options from top to bottom (and expanded when needed). HintText exists among properties but not HintTextColor (hovercolor, pressedcolor and so forth exists there).

Regarding the last part. I tried clicking the top item then changing fill. But this do not work since it changes the fill for the whole gallery, not the individual items. If i try to select the gallery, i see not menu option 'List Item' (i guess that is not what you mean).

Comment: In regards to Hinttext, when the options is are listed in letter order it will show Height, HintText, HoverBorderColor.

Comment: The ONLY properties i have found that can affect the individual gallery items is TemplateHeight and TemplatePadding. Both useless to me.